# Selenium WebDriver: Java: NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@id='manage_area']/ul/li/div[2]"}

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm having a real hard time interacting with this element.  I've used `FirePath`, Selenium IDE, and manual construction of an XPATH to no avail.  I'm trying to interact with "Group Accident".  I can get Selenium to detect "Accident" by using `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='manage_area']/ul/li/div")).click();`

I want to be able to open the menu and select "Add or View Plan/Options" from Group Accident.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAinK.jpg

Please help! Thanks.

Here's my code:

```
@Test
  public void testAddEEBenefitsinCOLO() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/bcs/stored.asp");
    driver.findElement(By.id("TBUserName")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("TBUserName")).sendKeys("test");
    driver.findElement(By.name("TBPassword")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.name("TBPassword")).sendKeys("pw1");
    driver.findElement(By.name("Login")).click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.findElement(By.name("TBPARAM")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.name("TBPARAM")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.name("TBPARAM")).sendKeys("colo1973");
    driver.findElement(By.name("TBPARAM")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
    driver.findElement(By.id("QRY")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("QRY")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("QRY")).sendKeys("Melvin");
    driver.findElement(By.name("B1")).click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='manage_area']/ul/li/div[2]")).click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
```

Error message:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@id='manage_area']/ul/li/div[2]"}
Command duration or timeout: 30.01 seconds
```

HTML:

```
<div class="spAbove">
</div>

<div class="tableholder" id="ben110119014" style="width: 99%">

        <form method="post" id="submitform110119014" action="EnrollChange.asp" name="ACCIDENT"
            onsubmit="JavaScript: return validateChangeType(this); ">
            <input type="hidden" name="TARGET" value="110119014" />

                    <h3>
                    <span onmouseover="javascript:showtip('BC110119014')">
                    Accident
                    </span>
                    <div id="manage_area" style="margin-left: -5px; visibility: hidden; display: inline;">
                        <a href="javascript:spawn_window('glossary.asp?PPVS=COLO1973#0','600','800','',0)"
                        title="What's this?">
                        <img src="images/help.gif" border="0"></a>
                    </div>

                    </h3>

                    <table class="textNormal sp" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>

                            <td class="tdata" valign="middle">
                                <input type="hidden" name="CHANGETYPE" id="Hidden1" value="0" />

                                    <div id="manage_area">
                                        <ul class="menuUL opMenu" title="Click here to view your options">
                                            <li class="menuLI width225">

                                            <div class="titleCell optImg" title="Click here to view your options">  

                                                <ul class="menuUL MainOptSubMenu">

                                                                <li class="menuLI"><a href="javascript: submitBenefit('16', 'submitform110119014'); "
                                                                value="16">
                                                                Add: Initial Population</a></li>

                                                                <li class="menuLI"><a href="javascript: submitBenefit('46', 'submitform110119014'); "
                                                                value="46">
                                                                Decline Benefit: (Prompt Effective)</a></li>

                                                                <li class="menuLI"><a href="javascript: submitBenefit('81', 'submitform110119014'); "
                                                                value="81">
                                                                Add or View Plan/Options</a></li>

                                                                <li class="menuLI"><a href="javascript: submitBenefit('64', 'submitform110119014'); "
                                                                value="64">
                                                                Decline Benefit</a></li>

                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>

                            </td>
                        </tr>





                        </tbody>
                    </table>

        </div>
        <p align="right" class="backtotop">
            <a href="#PAGETOP">To Top</a></p>
        <input type="hidden" name="TRANSID" value="5327418">
        <input type="hidden" name="PPVS" value="COLO1973">
        <input type="hidden" name="HST" value="SITE,BENEFITS,">
        <input type="hidden" name="PF" value="BENEFITS">
        <input type="hidden" name="SK" value="140062328">
        <input type="hidden" name="BENCAT" value="ACCIDENT">
        <input type="hidden" name="CANCHANGE" value="">
    </form>

<div class="tableholder" id="ben167876400" style="width: 99%">

        <form method="post" id="submitform167876400" action="EnrollChange.asp" name="GRPACC"
            onsubmit="JavaScript: return validateChangeType(this); ">
            <input type="hidden" name="TARGET" value="167876400" />

                    <h3>
                    <span onmouseover="javascript:showtip('BC167876400')">
                    Group Accident
                    </span>
                    <div id="manage_area" style="margin-left: -5px; visibility: hidden; display: inline;">
                        <a href="javascript:spawn_window('glossary.asp?PPVS=COLO1973#0','600','800','',0)"
                        title="What's this?">
                        <img src="images/help.gif" border="0"></a>
                    </div>

                    </h3>

                    <table class="textNormal sp" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>

                            <td class="tdata" valign="middle">
                                <input type="hidden" name="CHANGETYPE" id="Hidden1" value="0" />

                                    <div id="manage_area">
                                        <ul class="menuUL opMenu" title="Click here to view your options">
                                            <li class="menuLI width225">

                                            <div class="titleCell optImg" title="Click here to view your options">  

                                                <ul class="menuUL MainOptSubMenu">

                                                                <li class="menuLI"><a href="javascript: submitBenefit('16', 'submitform167876400'); "
                                                                value="16">
                                                                Add: Initial Population</a></li>

                                                                <li class="menuLI"><a href="javascript: submitBenefit('46', 'submitform167876400'); "
                                                                value="46">
                                                                Decline Benefit: (Prompt Effective)</a></li>

                                                                <li class="menuLI"><a href="javascript: submitBenefit('81', 'submitform167876400'); "
                                                                value="81">
                                                                Add or View Plan/Options</a></li>

                                                                <li class="menuLI"><a href="javascript: submitBenefit('64', 'submitform167876400'); "
                                                                value="64">
                                                                Decline Benefit</a></li>

                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>

                            </td>
                        </tr>





                        </tbody>
                    </table>

        </div>
```

Comment: Which element you want to find Group Accident, Add: Initial Population,Decline Benefit,..????Please reconstruct your question?

Comment: I would like to interact with Add or View Plan/Options from Group Accident:

http://i.imgur.com/gHMaXLl.jpg

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Add or View Plan/Options")).click();
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Add or View Plan/Options')]")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML code snippet, since **"Add or View/Plan Options"** is present in 2 forms above, so below is the way to click on the One under **"Manage Benefit"** of **"Group Accident"**:

1- Click on the **"Manage Benefits"** button of **"Group Accident"** using this code, so that the dropdown is visible:

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id='submitform167876400']//ul[@class='menuUL opMenu']")).click();`

2- Click on the **"Add or View/Plan Options"** submenu item under it.

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id='submitform167876400']//a[contains(text(),'Add or View Plan/Options')]")).click();`

Comment: Thanks, Subh.  The first line for making the dropdown visible works but the second line doesn't click on Add or View/Plan Options.  I tried adding .click(); to the second line but that didn't work either.  Any idea why it's not able click it?

Comment: Is it giving any error or something, for the second line that is ?

Comment: No it actually thinks the test passes even though it never clicks on the link.

Comment: Okay.. **Add an explicit wait before clicking then**. Like this: `WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//form[@id='submitform167876400']//a[contains(text(),'Add or View Plan/Options')]")));`. **And then click on the element :** 
  `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id='submitform167876400']//a[contains(text(),'Add or View Plan/Options')]")).click();`

Comment: I'm not sure why that didn't work.  It timed out after 30 seconds.  Here's what I did to fix it:
After your suggestion in #1, I added driver.findElement(By.linkText("Add or View Plan/Options")).click(); and it works.  

Now the problem I have is when I run the script, I need it to scroll down. Javascript executor throws a java null pointer exception.  Any idea why?  Thanks

Comment: @Vbp6us: Okay. Something must be missing in my code. :) Any ways, you say it works after your tweak. Why you need to perform scroll using JavascriptExecutor then? Any specific thing you want to perform in there? If so can you please provide the code for that. It will be easier to comprehend then. Thanks :)

Comment: I was using JavaScript executor for scrolling as you said, I'd I wanted to interact with one of the manage areas further down on the page. I fixed the null pointer by placing the executor code in @test.You're really good at this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad that you worked it out.. And, Pleasure's all mine.. :) @Vbp6us